# define columns and rows in arraylist using hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap the key is `Integer` (represent rows No.) and the value is an array object (has fraction numbers)
`HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Number>>`

> Number is a class has methods to do calculation on fraction

The user should enter number of rows and columns and enter fraction numbers.

I filled the hash map without errors but they asked us to retrieve the fraction number by entering row No. and column No by the following method:

> The class has a `public method Number getItem(int rowNO, int colNO)` which gets and returns the specific number item in the matrix according to the given argument. Ex. `getItem(2, 3)` returns `1/3`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's similar how you fill the HashMap with data.

As verbose steps

```
public Number getItem(int rowNO, int colNO) {
    // get the data for the row
    ArrayList<Number> row = yourMap.get(rowNO);
    // get the value of a specific column of that row
    Number value = row.get(colNO);
    return value;
}
```

or shorthand

```
public Number getItem(int rowNO, int colNO) {
    return yourMap.get(rowNO).get(colNO);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly by using this method:                                                public Number getItem(int rowNO, int colNO) {
    return hMap.get(rowNO).get(colNO-1);
}                                                                                                                           thank you so much